Is there a way to get the property name of an index accessor?
I used Object.defineProperty to define some properties for personZoo. How can I make personZoo have those defined property types?
You can modify these codes as you see fit, as long as they meet the requirements.I don't quite understand the advanced operations of types, I hope you can explain the reason. Thanks!!
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  behavior: {
    [key: string | symbol]: () => string;
  };
}

type PersonZoo = typeof personZoo;
const personZoo = {
  zooName: "person zoo",
};

type MergeReturnType<T, K extends IPerson> = T & {
  // ???
};

function merge<T extends IPerson>(
  obj1: typeof personZoo,
  obj2: readonly T[],
): MergeReturnType<PersonZoo, T> {
  obj2.forEach((p) => {
    Object.defineProperty(obj1, p.name, {
      get() {
        return new Proxy(p.behavior, {
          get(target, key) {
            return target[key];
          },
        });
      },
    });
  });

  return obj1 as MergeReturnType<PersonZoo, T>;
}

const personArr: IPerson[] = [
  {
    name: "n1",
    behavior: {
      loudly: () => "speak loudly",
    },
  },
  {
    name: "n2",
    behavior: {
      singing: () => "singing",
    },
  },
] as const;
const xx = merge(personZoo, personArr);
// expect
xx.n1.loudly()
xx.n2.sining();


Note that in order for this to possibly work, you simply cannot annotate your personArr variable:
const personArr: IPerson[] = [ ⋯ ] as const;

If you do that, then the type of personArr is just IPerson[]; any more specific information about the array literal you've assigned to it has been lost. You do need the const assertion to keep track of the name properties, but if you annotate personArr then you're throwing that information away. Leave
off the annotation:
const personArr = [ ⋯ ] as const;


After that, given the code as written, I'd define MergeReturnType<T, U> as follows:
type MergeReturnType<T, U extends IPerson> =
    T & { [V in U as V["name"]]: V["behavior"] };

You expect U to be a union of subtypes of IPerson where the name and behavior properties have specific information you care about. The type after T & is a key-remapped mapped type, where we iterate over each union member of U with a new type parameter V. For each such member V, the key of the resulting output property is the type of its name property, so we use the indexed access type V["name"]. And the value of the resulting output property is the type of its behavior property, so we use the indexed access type V["behavior"].
Let's test that out:
const personArr = [
    { name: "n1", behavior: { loudly: () => "speak loudly" } },
    { name: "n2", behavior: { singing: () => "singing" } },
] as const;
/* const personArr: readonly [{
    readonly name: "n1";
    readonly behavior: {
        readonly loudly: () => string;
    };
}, {
    readonly name: "n2";
    readonly behavior: {
        readonly singing: () => string;
    };
}] */

const xx = merge(personZoo, personArr);
/*const xx: {
    zooName: string;
} & {
    n1: {
        readonly loudly: () => string;
    };
    n2: {
        readonly singing: () => string;
    };
} */

Looks good, the xx variable has an n1 property of type {loudly(): string} and an n2 property of type {singing(): string}, meaning the following code compiles as expected:
console.log(xx.n1.loudly().toUpperCase());
console.log(xx.n2.singing().toUpperCase());

Playground link to code
